# ValueError: Variable Embedding already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True in VarScope? Originally defined

Tags: classification, text-classification, recurrent-neural-network, multilabel-classification, fasttext

Based on this github link https://github.com/brightmart/text_classification/tree/master/a03_TextRNN While I run **train a03_TextRNN** with **google_news_wor22vec.bin** and a **text file with my documents + labels**, I've got these errors :

**How can I solve this issue?**

[image: error image]

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "p8_TextRNN_train.py", line 184, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/home/eslami/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "p8_TextRNN_train.py", line 68, in main
    vocab_size, FLAGS.embed_size, FLAGS.is_training)
  File "/home/eslami/Downloads/all-kind-text_classification-master/a03_TextRNN/p8_TextRNN_model.py", line 33, in init
    self.instantiate_weights()
  File "/home/eslami/Downloads/all-kind-text_classification-master/a03_TextRNN/p8_TextRNN_model.py", line 45, in instantiate_weights
    self.Embedding = tf.get_variable("Embedding",shape=[self.vocab_size, self.embed_size],initializer=self.initializer) #[vocab_size,embed_size] tf.random_uniform([self.vocab_size, self.embed_size],-1.0,1.0)
  File "/home/eslami/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 1065, in get_variable
    use_resource=use_resource, custom_getter=custom_getter)
  File "/home/eslami/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 962, in get_variable
    use_resource=use_resource, custom_getter=custom_getter)
  File "/home/eslami/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 367, in get_variable
    validate_shape=validate_shape, use_resource=use_resource)
  File "/home/eslami/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 352, in _true_getter
    use_resource=use_resource)
      File "/home/eslami/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 664, in _get_single_variable
        name, "".join(traceback.format_list(tb))))

    ValueError: Variable Embedding already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True in VarScope? Originally defined at:
File "/home/eslami/Downloads/all-kind-text_classification-master/a03_TextRNN/p8_TextRNN_model.py", line 45, in instantiate_weights
    self.Embedding = tf.get_variable("Embedding",shape=[self.vocab_size, self.embed_size],initializer=self.initializer) #[vocab_size,embed_size] tf.random_uniform([self.vocab_size, self.embed_size],-1.0,1.0)
  File "/home/eslami/Downloads/all-kind-text_classification-master/a03_TextRNN/p8_TextRNN_model.py", line 33, in init
    self.instantiate_weights()
  File "/home/eslami/Downloads/all-kind-text_classification-master/a03_TextRNN/p8_TextRNN_model.py", line 123, in test
    textRNN=TextRNN(num_classes, learning_rate, batch_size, decay_steps, decay_rate,sequence_length,vocab_size,embed_size,is_training)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is very late, but I found your post as I was looking to solve a similar problem. In case anyone else finds there way here, add this code at the beginning of your model will solve the issue:

```html
tf.reset_default_graph()
```